# Will change AWS RDS storage type (from Magnetic to GP2) cause downtime and data loss?

Tags: amazon-rds

I have an RDS db (db.t3.micro) with Magnetic storage type. I'd like to change it to GP2 but I'm now sure about the duration of the downtime (nor I can find it in the doc).

Will it continue working during the "migration"?

Furthermore, could I get any data loss?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.ModifyingExisting:~:text=instance%20storage.-,Modifying%20settings%20for%20Provisioned%20IOPS%20SSD%20storage,-You%20can%20modify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html#USER_PIOPS.ModifyingExisting:%7E:text=instance%20storage.-,Modifying%20settings%20for%20Provisioned%20IOPS%20SSD%20storage,-You%20can%20modify) there will not be any outage and degrade performance

> You can modify the settings for a DB instance that uses Provisioned IOPS SSD storage by using the Amazon RDS console, AWS CLI, or Amazon RDS API. Specify the storage type, allocated storage, and the amount of Provisioned IOPS that you require. The range depends on your database engine and instance type.
>
> Although you can reduce the amount of IOPS provisioned for your instance, you can't reduce the storage size.
>
> In most cases, scaling storage doesn't require any outage and doesn't degrade performance of the server. After you modify the storage IOPS for a DB instance, the status of the DB instance is storage-optimization.